# Вложить pdf или doc в приложение Android

Tags: android, pdf, doc

Возможно ли добавить в приложение (например, в Assets) какой-то Winword документ или pdf файл? Чтобы приложение по запросу могло переслать его куда-либо (например, на почту).

Если да, то в каком виде и куда его добавлять и как реализовать код пересылки?

Если нет, то подскажите, что из оптимального можно использовать вместо этого?

Comment: Посмотрите здесь пример отправки файла через email,  возможно это вам поможет.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974987/how-to-send-an-email-with-a-file-attachment-in-android

Comment: Возможно. Например, если есть метод в API для отправки такого контента или же через встроенную почту. Вот для примера [http://droidmentor.com/document-attachment/](ссылка)

Comment: @Serj, отлично, спасибо, помогло! :) единственное, там нигде не указано, что для корректного сохранения файла у приложения должны быть соответствующие разрешения (на этапе начальной разработки это неочевидно :) ). Оформите как ответ, я отмечу :)

Comment: @Jarvis_J готово)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно. 
Необходимо добавить соответствующий файл в папку **assets**
После чего этот файл можно будет отправить через:

1. метод в API для отправки такого контента
2. встроенную почту. [Пример](http://droidmentor.com/document-attachment/)